# How to use a command that takes one argument as a declaration?

Tags: macros, latexdiff, ulem

I would like to apply `\sout{}` from the `ulem` package to anything between `\DIFdelbegin` and `\DIFdelend` below (commands from the Latexdiff script). Can the definitions of the two commands be modified in this way? LaTeX would need to be instructed that the `\sout{}` argument starts after `\DIFdelbegin` and ends at `\DIFdelend`.

Is there a generic solution that would also work with other commands that take one argument (e.g., `\emph{}`, `\textsc{}`)?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelbegin}{\protect\color{red}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\providecommand{\DIFdelend}{\protect\color{black}} %DIF PREAMBLE
\begin{document}
Lorem \DIFdelbegin ipsum dolor \DIFdelend sit amet.
\end{document}
```

Desired output:

[image]

Comment: I think you will get a lot of grief from this approach from all but the simplest documents. There are many commands that will break when in the argument of a \sout. This is precisely why latexdiff implements this complicated marking scheme with \DIFdelbegin \DEFdelend  and \DIFdel.  You don't really say what your ultimate purpose is here, but there is almost definitely a better way to achieve this (look at the latexdiff cmd type options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage[normalem]{ulem} %DIF PREAMBLE
\RequirePackage{color} %DIF PREAMBLE
\def\DIFdelbegin#1\DIFdelend{\sout{#1}}
\begin{document}
Lorem \DIFdelbegin ipsum dolor \DIFdelend sit amet.
\end{document}
```

But it will not like it, if there is a paragraph break in the text.